# awk command for reading files that are the contents of another file

Tags: awk

I have a file named file1.txt that contains the lines:

```
e1.txt
e2.txt
```

These are files themselves existing in the same directory.

I want to use an `awk` command on `file1.txt` so as to read its contents(`e1.txt` and `e2.txt`) and print the contents of those files

I have tried `awk '{cat $0}' file1.txt` but it produces no result.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable.html#Getline_002fVariable) loop around each file (`e1.txt`, `e2.txt` etc) contained in `file1.txt`, like so

```
awk '{ while ((getline a < $0) > 0) print a }' file1.txt
```

Alternately you could call out to `cat` via [system](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html) but this could be fraught with peril if the contents of `file1.txt` are not under your control

```
 awk '{ system("cat "$0) }' file1.txt
```

Or just don't bother with `awk`

```
 xargs -d '\n' cat <file1.txt
```